# Display properties of an object based on value using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jsp

I'm trying to display properties of an object based on value. So basically if they value of the property is equal to "film" the property should display. This is the code I have so far:

```
<% fidos.forEach(fido => { %>
        <%=fido.renown === "Film" %>
    <% }) %>
```

The browser returns:

true true false false false false false false

But I would like it to display the name and image for the 2 true ones. I believe I should try an if else statement but I'm not sure how to set it up. I've tried:

```
<% fidos.forEach(fido => { %>
         <% if fido.renown === "Film" { %>
            <%=fido.name%>
         <a href="/fidofame/<%=fido._id; %>">
            <<img class="image" src=<%=fido.image %> alt=<%=fido.name %>> -->
        <</a>
        <% } else %>
    <% }) %>
```

This returns a SyntaxError to the browser. I'm sorry for this basic question. I've only been programing for like 2 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses on the if condition and quotation marks on `src` and `alt`. This should work:

```
<% fidos.forEach(fido => { %>
  <% if (fido.renown === "Film") { %>
    <%= fido.name %>
    <a href="/fidofame/<%= fido._id %>">
      <img class="image" src="<%= fido.image %>" alt="<%= fido.name %>" />
    </a>
  <% } %>
<% }) %>
```